# A unix command to truncate each line of a file

Tags: text-processing, ksh, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to truncate it from the third semicolon. For example, if I have this file:

```
1;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
```

I want to get the following output:

```
1;foo;bar
2;foo;bar
3;foo;bar
```

I don't know what kind of Unix command I can use for that. What do you suggest?

Note that this manipulation will be done on a KSH script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the sake of variety, here's another way with `cut`:

```
cut -d \; -f -3
```

Comment: I've never really learned to use `cut`. :-)

Comment: wouldn't it be `cut -d \; -f 3`?

Comment: @gt6989b No, that would print the third field. `-3` says to print all fields up to and including the third field.

Comment: @ChrisDown, thanks, was thinking about `-f 1-3`, this is a useful shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

This will accomplish what you ask:

```
awk -F';' '{print $1 ";" $2 ";" $3;}' <input >output
```

The `awk` utility is well designed for this task. It can easily cut up individual lines into fields, then manipulate them based on that. The `-F';'` argument tells `awk` to use `;` as the field separator. The quotes are necessary because the shell would interpret `;` as a command separator without them.

The command given to awk to execute for each line (the `'{print $1 ";" $2 ";" $3;}'` bit) is similarly quoted to keep all the funny characters (`{`, `}`, `$`, `"` and `;` in this case) from being treated specially by the shell and make sure the whole thing is passed to `awk` as one unit.

And, of course, `<input` and `>output` are the redirection directives being given to the shell to redirect the command's input and output from and to a file.

Comment: You need to set `OFS`, otherwise the ';' will be converted to spaces.

Comment: @jordanm: _nod_ That's one way. The other way is just to put the literal ';' characters in there. :-) I wasn't sure if `,` would do what I wanted, which is why I had to test it.

Comment: Most of the current `awk`s allow this shorter way: `awk -F';' -vOFS=';' 'NF=3'`. (With extra precaution: `awk -F';' -vOFS=';' 'NF>3{NF=3}1'`.)

Comment: @manatwork I like your answer the most.

Comment: @manatwork: Wow. I suppose that makes sense. But it's starting to get perlish in its terse obscurity.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using awk, which is not dependent on the shell. You will need to write the output to a temporary file, and then move it on top of the existing one.

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN { OFS=";" } { print $1,$2,$3 }' file.txt > newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the greatest alternative, just in case you need in-place editing and wish to solve it with `sed`:

```
sed -i ':b;s/;[^;]*//3;tb' file.txt
```

Comment: Systems that have ksh usually don't have GNU sed, and `sed -i` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Doh! I checked every used `sed` command against the POSIX specification before posting, but I forgot the command line option. (By the way, personally I always have a `ksh` implementation on my Linuxes, either [Public Domain Korn Shell](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/) or [MirBSD™ Korn Shell](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm).)

Comment: And allowing things after the `:` command is also a GNU extension. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html) clearly says you can't have semicolon followed by other commands after `:`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -lane '   @F =  split(";"); print join ";", @F[0..2];'  file
```

**Using Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
$~ raku   -ne 'my @F = .split(";");   put join ";", @F[0..2];'  file
```

Here are two answers using Perl and Raku, respectively. Data is read-in linewise using the Perl `-lane` or Raku `-ne` non-autoprinting flags. (The difference is Raku performs the `-l` autochomping by default, however Raku doesn't have the `-a` flag).

After this, the code is virtually identical. In Raku you have to declare the `@F` (or `@G`, or `@H` array, etc.) with `my` or `our` (scope descriptor). Also Raku demands that you indicate ***what*** object you're calling `split` on (`.split` is short for `$_.split` meaning the `$_` topic variable, which holds individual lines of data as they are read-in).

Finally you either `print` (Perl) or `put` (Raku). Raku has `print` as well, but `put` adds a newline terminator for you.

Sample Input:

```
1;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
```

Sample Output:

```
1;foo;bar
2;foo;bar
3;foo;bar
```

*Perl References:*
https://perldoc.perl.org
https://www.perl.org

*Raku References:*
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org