# How to use cut command to get the first and last elements of a row?

Tags: text-processing, ksh, cut

I've asked almost [the same question already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55625/a-unix-command-to-truncate-each-line-of-a-file), but this time, I want to retrieve the X **latest** elements of a row of a CSV file. For example, with an input file as this one:

```
1;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;baz;x;y;z
```

What would be the command (eventually using `cut`) to get the last 2 columns, so I get:

```
y;z
y;z
y;z
```

In fact, my real target is to retrieve the first 3 **and** the last 2 fields of each row, so I get:

```
1;foo;bar;y;z
2;foo;bar;y;z
3;foo;bar;y;z
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use a command like `cut -d \; -f 1-3,10-11` (if there are 11 elements in the row), because the CSV file does not respect the *real* CSV format. Indeed, some fields in the middle of the rows are *encrypted*, and their encrypted value may sometimes contains a `;` characters (and of course, they are not wrapped inside `"`). In others words, my lines may look like that:

```
1;foo;bar;#@$"é&^l#;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;#¤=é;)o'#;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;#]]'~é{{#;baz;x;y;z
```

and as you can see, on the second line, there is an additional `;` character, so I can't use here a command like `cut -d \; -f 1-3,7-8`, because if will return that, which is wrong:

```
1;foo;bar;y;z
2;foo;bar;x;y  (-> Wrong here, there is a shift)
3;foo;bar;y;z
```

So how can I use `cut` to solve my problem?

Thanks

ps: I am specially in love with the `cut` command, so if you have a command that does what I want but that is not `cut`, then it's fine too :)

*Edit* It seems important to note that the machine is quite old: `uname -a` give this message:

```
SunOS ###### 5.10 Generic_142900-05 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240
```

and some commands may not be present (like `rev`)

Comment: If your file has fixed width fields, you can use the -b option to select items via byte or -c for characters, rather than -f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your version of `SunOS` `nawk`(or for that matter `awk`) should be able to do the trick

```
 nawk -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{print($1,$2,$3,$(NF-1),$(NF))}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a multiple-command solution for retrieving the first 3 and the last 2 fields using only `cut`, `rev` (for reversing) and shell-builtins:

```
while read line
do
    first=$(echo -n "$line" | cut -d ";" -f -3)
    second=$(echo -n "$line" | rev | cut -d ";" -f -2 | rev)
    echo "$first;$second"
done < my_file
```

These statements can also be put into a single line, of course.

EDIT:

I gathered some one-line alternatives to `rev` (which omit printing the final *'\n'*):

python: `python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(raw_input()[::-1])`

perl: `perl -ne 'chomp;print scalar reverse;'`

and there are a lot more possibilities for [reversing a string](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reverse_a_string). Maybe some of those work on your system.

Comment: Argh. Your solution seems interesting, but unfortunately, the command `rev` is not installed on my server (SunOS 5.10)

Comment: @romaintaz Too bad, my `rev` comes from the `util-linux` package which contains various essential commands for Linux. I wonder whether SunOS has a similar command.

Comment: perl (5.8.4!) is present on my Solaris 10 and (even that) can do the field-split and select all by itself in one go: `perl -lane '@F=split(";"); print join ";",@F[0..2,-2,-1]' <in >out`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 and here's the Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) version, although you'd have to build it from source for SunOS/Solaris: `raku -ne 'my @F = .split(";"); put join ";", @F[0..2,*-2,*-1];'`

Answer (score 2):

```
% cat a
1;foo;bar;#@$"é&^l#;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;#¤=é;)o'#;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;#]]'~é{{#;baz;x;y;z
% sed -r 's,^(([^;]+;){3}).*;([^;]+;[^;]+)$,\1\3,' < a
1;foo;bar;y;z
2;foo;bar;y;z
3;foo;bar;y;z
```

Comment: I fear that my version of `sed` is too old, as your command is throwing a `sed: illegal option -- r` message :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came across this question for the same reason and found an alternative with cut as requested. Remember that reverse function is really useful to avoid going in the middle part.

Here is my solution:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/fixup.csv
1;foo;bar;#@$"é&^l#;baz;x;y;z
2;foo;bar;#¤=é;)o'#;baz;x;y;z
3;foo;bar;#]]'~é{{#;baz;x;y;z
$ cat /tmp/fixup.csv |cut -d ';' -f-3 > begin.txt
$ cat /tmp/fixup/file.txt |rev |cut -d ';' -f-2|rev > end.txt
$ paste -d";" begin.txt end.txt > result.csv
$ cat result.csv
1;foo;bar;y;z
2;foo;bar;y;z
3;foo;bar;y;z
$
```

Comment: But as noted 11 years ago, `rev` does not exist on Solaris-aka-SunOS 10. Although very nearly standard on Linux it is _not_ POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Although personally I'd go with the awk or perl methods, this can also be done, without lots of extra processes, with builtins in the bash 3.2 on (my now-archived) Solaris 10:

```
# unless in a one-off script, save IFS first and restore afterwards
# most simply just put this in parens so it runs in a subshell
IFS=';'; while read -ra a;do N=${#a[*]}; 
  set -- "${a[0]}" "${a[1]}" "${a[2]}" "${a[N-2]}" "${a[N-1]}";
  printf %s\\n "${*}";done  <in >out
```

Comment: That doesn't work properly for lines where the last field is empty (in bash, would be OK in zsh; where you need -A instead of -a like in most other shells). See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) (though here it's not as bad as in scai's answer)